# java.io.FileNotFoundException when trying to run script with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When I am trying to run script with selenium I am getting the following error

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Shantu!!!!!!! (The system cannot
>   find the file specified) Build info: version: '2.49.1', revision:
>   '7203e46', time: '2016-01-21 17:35:35' System info: host:
>   'ghijkl-ab562296', ip: '192.168.43.128', os.name: 'Windows XP',
>   os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.8.0_40' Driver
>   info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.onlyOverrideThisIfYouKnowWhatYouAreDoing(FirefoxProfile.java:132)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.(FirefoxProfile.java:85)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.(FirefoxProfile.java:78)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.(FirefoxProfile.java:67)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.getProfile(FirefoxDriver.java:288)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:264)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
>     at practicePackage.New.main(New.java:11) Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Shantu!!!!!!! (The system cannot
>   find the file specified)  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.onlyOverrideThisIfYouKnowWhatYouAreDoing(FirefoxProfile.java:130)
>     ... 11 more

Comment: please provide the code..

Comment: Please find the code below                          package practicePackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class New {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  
  driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=t-WmVunNIqrG8Aeg0ImABw&gws_rd=ssl");

 }

}

Comment: please check answer..thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the exception is thrown when you are trying to test the application using a specific firefox profile that you have created.

Comment: Can u please guide me how to know whether i have created firefox profile.

Thanks
Shantaveer B

Comment: Although it looks like you called `new FirefoxDriver()` I would guess you've also set the `webdriver.firefox.profile` System property to point to `D:\Shantu!!!!!!!`. As there isn't a valid profile there, just remove the property and the browser will pick up the default one when it starts.

Answer (score 0):

When ever trying to get any URL, we need to provide complete URL means including with http://...

```
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Can you please try like this.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: i tried the same still i am facing the same exception

Thanks
Shantaveer B

Comment: what version of firefox it is? is browser is starting?

Comment: one more thing is please check firefox is installed in default location or not ie program files

Comment: Firefox version is 43.0.4

Comment: is browser is starting on execution?

Comment: may i know very is firefox installed.. please install in program files and see, else we need to use FirefoxBinary to specify its location in script

Comment: In below path firefox has been installed

C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox

Comment: every thing is correct, i am expecting the jar is corrupted. please down down load new jar and can you try again ? http://goo.gl/rQhaxb

Comment: Will let u know once it is done and thanks for support


Thanks
Shantaveer B

Comment: Hi murali,
Still m facing the same issue even after downloaded the new jars again.

Comment: Are using single selenium stand alone jar

Comment: If you are using java jars, please give all jars in build path. You can find multiple jars in different folders if you downloaded java jars.please give all in build path

Comment: Yes i am using selenium stand alone jar

Comment: I attached below jars in build path

selenium-java-2.49.1, selenium-java-2.49.1-srcs and all jars in libs folder

Comment: Even i changed the workspace path still same is displayed means D:\Shantu!!! In exception.

Comment: Hi Murali

Can you please provide me your mail ID, to reach you immediately if come across any issues. 

Reply me with ur mail ID if you have no issue 
mail ID: shantavir219@gmail.com


Thanks
Shantaveer Biradar